# Fixed row and column in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html table with a fixed width and height and overflow set as scroll. I want the first row to be fixed while scrolling in vertical direction and first column to be fixed while scrolling horizontally. I don't have a thead.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 11</td>
    <td>Value 12</td>
    <td>Value 13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 21</td>
    <td>Value 22</td>
    <td>Value 23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 31</td>
    <td>Value 32</td>
    <td>Value 33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 41</td>
    <td>Value 42</td>
    <td>Value 43</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add some code so we can inspect the problem further.

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this but ignore the js part, it's only used to generate the large table. your solution is in the CSS part

```js
// generate table
var row = '<tr>',rowLen=100,colLen=100,content='';

for(var i=0;i<rowLen;i++)
 row+= '<td>text'+i+'</td>';
row+= '</tr>';

for(var j=0;j<colLen;j++)
 content+=row;
document.getElementsByClassName('freezHeaderAndTitle')[0].innerHTML=content;
```

```css
.freezHeaderAndTitle{
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.freezHeaderAndTitle td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.freezHeaderAndTitle tr:first-of-type td{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.freezHeaderAndTitle td:first-of-type{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0px;
}

/* Edit: corner fixed always */
.freezHeaderAndTitle tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type{
  z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<table class="freezHeaderAndTitle">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But td (0,0) should be fixed in both cases.

Comment: @Akhtar if you have a 2d table (top and side headers) the corner header always means nothing. but you can do that anyways by adding `z-index: 100;` for the first td. edit added to the solution ..